# Operator Overloading in C++ return

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading

I am new in C++ programming , I want to return object which was passed by default in operator overloading. Please help me on that.....

eg.

```
adi operator+(adi& s2){return s1;} 

main()
{
  s3=s1+s2;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking exactly, but your operator should take two arguments. I'd also recommend you take them by `const` reference.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) question. It has more information about overloading operators.

Comment: caebli3's link's good - specifically, look for the "Binary operators" heading in the top answer.

Comment: When I used *return this. I made it. I have successfully returned s1 which was implicitly passed to overloaded operator function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either implement operator+ as a class member

```
class A {
  A operator+(const A& rhs) const {
    A result; // do something with a
    // Pick one
    return result; // returns new object
    return rhs; // returns rhs parameter
    return *this; // returns current object
  }
};
```

Or as a non-member

```
A operator+(const A& a, const A& b) {
    A result; // do something with a
    return result; // returns new object
}
```

Comment: thanks. I got concept. I've to use return *this;

Answer (score 0):

It will look the following way

```
adi operator+( const adi &s2) const
{ 
   adi temp;
/* some calculations with temp*/ 

   return temp;
}
```

The symantic is the following: you create a new object that will be the sum of the object that calls the operator that is `this` ans the object passed to the operator as an argument. Neither the original object nor the arument should be changed.

Also the operator can be define as a non-member function. For example

```
adi operator+( const adi &s1, const adi &s2)
{ 
   adi temp;
/* some calculations with temp*/ 

   return temp;
}
```

Comment: thanks for help. but, I got. I hv to use return *this; to return s1 which was implicitly passed.